# Canvas prerendered terrain mouse picking

Tags: canvas, three.js, webgl, terrain, raycasting

I am working on a browser game (at design phase) that will have tile map. What I want to achieve is something like of Simcity 4

[image]

As webGL support and device capabilities are limited atm, I want a canvas fallback. In that case, rendering terrain at serverside and serving as chunks of image seemed a viable option.

But in that case, I am not sure how to handle mouse picking of a tile. My search led to two options which are mouse maps if you have limited number of slope types and raycasting if you go 3D with terrain.

As I have neither of them, I am not sure how to handle this, so would appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: First I would make sure you won't have any other issues using an image and not a 3D model. I wouldn't go for this solution personally. Then if you want to keep this solution will have to generate the mapping grid table server side, where you got all the positions of all your cases. And use it client side.

Comment: Doubt there is another choice considering webGL support and current performance of devices. Would love to hear your suggestion.

Comment: If you don't want to use webgl, I would try keeping the server image and overlay a clone of your terrain without rendering it. Then use the picking tool from Three.js.

Comment: Well, I decided to switch to webGL and use canvas/dom fallback if needed. Thanks again